# How do you get the index of a row in sapui5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I have a table that gets rows added to it dynamically. Right now I have 140 rows. The `visibleRowCount` is set to 20 like so:

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    id: "sapTable",
    title: "Table Example",
    visibleRowCount: 20,
    selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single
}).addStyleClass("alternate-color");
```

When I click on a row I want to find out the index. This is how I do it:

```
$("#myTable").on("tap", "tr", function (e) {
    // Works until you scroll the table - Top element becomes index of 1
    var index = this.rowIndex;
    console.log(index);
});
```

Which gets the correct index for the first 20 rows but once you start scrolling the table the index of the top row becomes 1 since the sapui5 table loads the information into the table on scroll. I think I am going to have to go about this a different way. Any ideas?

I will set up a jsbin tomorrow if needed.

Comment: Do you have control of the table structure? It might be as simple as adding a "Line Number ID" column, and then simply querying that to figure out which row you're actually at.

Comment: I'll test that out tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

When a row of a table is selected/deselected, a `rowSelectionChange` event is fired.

```
  var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    id: "sapTable",
    title: "Table Example",
    visibleRowCount: 20,
    selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
    rowSelectionChange: function(e) {
      var oIndex = e.getParameter('rowIndex');
      if (oTable.isIndexSelected(oIndex )) {
        var oContext= oTable.getContextByIndex(oIndex );
        var path = oContext.sPath;
        var object = oTable.getModel().getProperty(path);
        console.log(object);        
      }
    }
  }).addStyleClass("alternate-color");
```

Above in the code, we can get the selected or deselected row; then we use the `isIndexSelected` function to check if it is selected or deselected. And by getting the context and path, we are able to get the binding object itself.

Please note that if row 1 is already selected and now user select row 2, this event will not fire for that deselection of row 1, an event will be fired for selection of row 2.

Hope this helps!